# Probability and combinatorics - Find the expectancy of people in a line and in circle

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

$n$ men and $m$ women are standing in a line (randomly).
Find the expectancy of the number of men that stand beside a women (at least one side - left or right)
Harder question: Now solve it, but they stand in a circle and not a line.

I wanted to use an indicator:
$X = $ number of men standing beside at least one women.

$X_i = 1 ~~~\text{if standing besides a women} \\ ~~~~~~~~~~0~~~ \text{else}$

And so: $E[X] =E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i] =\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i]$

the problem is that I am having a time computing what is the probability a random men will stand next to a women (left or right or both)

+ How should I approach the harder question?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question, but these rvs are not independent. If you know that $n$ men stand behind the first woman, the probability of >0 men behind the second one is $0$, so $P[X_2=1|X_1=n]=0 \neq P[X_2=2]P[X_1=n]$, as neither of these two marginals is $0$

Comment: @Alex but in the question they said a hint: "use an indicator (the $X_i$ I wrote) for each man... so how would you solve it? I'm lost.. thank you !

Comment: @StackOMeow Indicators are indeed fine here, and dependence does not spoil that. We do not need independence for linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand the nature of your problem with the first question.

It is a good strategy to go for indicators here.

In what you call the "harder question" we have: $$\mathbb EX_1=P(X_1=1)=1-P(\text{man 1 has male neighbors})=$$$$1-\frac{\binom{n-1}2\binom{m}0}{\binom{n+m-1}2}=1-\frac{n-1}{n+m-1}\frac{n-2}{n+m-2}$$

Moreover by symmetry we have $\mathbb EX_i=\mathbb EX_1$ for every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ so that:$$\mathbb EX=n\mathbb EX_1=n\left(1-\frac{n-1}{n+m-1}\frac{n-2}{n+m-2}\right)$$

---

**addendum**:

To find $\mathbb EX_1=P(X_1=1)$ in the first problem is a bit harder.

If $E$ denotes the event then man 1 is at utmost left or utmost right position then we must split up:

We must split up in:$$P(X_1=1)=P(X_1=1\mid E)P(E)+P(X_1=1\mid E^{\complement})P(E^{\complement})$$

Here $P(E)=\frac2{n+m}$ and $P(X_1=1\mid E)=\frac{m}{n+m-1}$.

For $P(X_1=1\mid E^{\complement})$ we find what we found for $P(X_1=1)$ in the first problem.

Comment: But I still having a hard time solving the first one (which supposed to be easier) what should I take as an indicator? I am confused because I dont know how to calculate each probability of each indicator... thank you sir!

Comment: IMV the first problem is harder than the second. I have added something.